# Pandas, Docx error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'paragraphs" when tring to write to docx from an excel file source

Tags: python, pandas, docx

I am trying to pull data from an excel file using pandas, then using a astype(string) and trying to write the string into a docx file using the docx library. I am new to programming and cannot figure out why this is not working. If I print the result I get (B1, B2) back as I expect and want, but it falls apart when inserting into docx. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing here?

```
import pandas as pd
import docx
file = ('file.xlsx')
test_type = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=6)
test_type_value = test_type['insertcolumn'].values
test_type_value_string = test_type_value.astype("string")
doc = 'file2.docx'
input_address1_1 = doc.paragraphs[3]
input_address1_1.add_run(test_type_value_string)
```

Comment: your error comes from this line: `input_address1_1 = doc.paragraphs[3]`: you've defined `doc` as a string. Maybe you meant to read `'file2.docx'` with the `docx` package?

Comment: It should be reading the 'file' as the excel document and writing to 'doc' as the word (docx) document.

Comment: yeah - right now you've just assigned the variable `doc` to the string `file2.docx`. You probably want to read the actual file with something like `doc = docx.Document('file2.docx')`